# swift how to handle the nsjson inside a session

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

this is my code

```
let session =  NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/......")
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error ) in
            if error != nil{
                print("error code = \(error!.code)")
                print("error = \(error!)")
            }else{

                let resultJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())

                print("data = \(resultJSON)")

            }
        })
        task.resume()
```

i didn't know how to handle the `try` for the `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` because i don't know if i have to throw exception out of the closure of not and really i am new to swift

Comment: After 9 knows, no answer, not even a single comment, and just 9 views? Apple must provide developers to help people in SOF.

Comment: Why should Apple provided employees to help people on SO?

Comment: @NathanOliver because not a lot of developers yet know swift, as you see, after 12 hours of posting a question, i still got 15 views and no answer and no comment. no problem i solved it, but i meant if it was java, man oh man, too many users would have helped me

Comment: Yeah but those people are not paid by Oracle to help answer java questions.  Most people on here donate their time and knowledge.  You need to be patient.  You are also posting in [non peak hours](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/).

Comment: @NathanOliver yes you are right, and I am patient, i didn't say anything wrong, and I didn't say any false data. you can check the number of views and the number of comments (none) and the number of answers (none), i just said that not a lot of interest in swift yet (and that is correct), i totally understand the reason.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Swift is a very active language on SO. Stating that the language activity is poor only because your question has not been answered is not accurate. And by the way this question has been answered [many times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift2%5D+json+try) already: it *may* explain the tumbleweed effect. :)

Comment: @EricD. i hope swift will be active really. nevertheless, i like swift and will try my best to help people (even though i am new to it yet). one more time, i didn't say anything wrong, it is more than half a day and 18 views :) that doesn't mean i say bad things about swift, i just say my experience. anyway, i got a solution, thanks

Comment: @EricD. after 12 days, there are 27 views :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution finally

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error ) in
            if error != nil{
                print("error code = \(error!.code)")
                print("error = \(error!)")
            }else{
                do{
                    let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())

                    let arrayJSON = resultJSON as! NSArray

                    for index in arrayJSON{
                        print("\(index)")
                    }
                }catch _{
                    print("received none formatted json")
                    print("\(data!)")
                }

            }
        })
        task.resume()
```